# Saving User's card in Square Payments

Tags: node.js, react-native, square

I'm new to Square and want to implement it in a React Native app with a Node backend.

I see that there is a method to save the customer's card details.
https://github.com/square/square-nodejs-sdk/blob/master/src/api/customersApi.ts#L230

But there is also the payment form?
https://developer.squareup.com/docs/payment-form/how-it-works

Firstly, I cannot see if the payment form is even available in React Native - information seems very scarce.

Secondly, even if I do implement that form, I can't see a way to connect it to the customers API endpoint.

I don't want to use in-app payments (i.e. google or apple pay). I want to be able to save card details like Amazon does, and use them whenever a user places an order in app (probably triggered by a node process). I'm not sure if I'm going about this the correct way, guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In-App Payments SDK will be the way to go (and there is a [React Native plugin](https://developer.squareup.com/docs/in-app-payments-sdk/react-native) already). The In-App Payments SDK is basically a mobile Square Payment Form, that you linked to. It will generate a secure nonce, and you can use the nonce to save the card on file. The next time the customer comes, instead of bringing up In-App Payments, you can simply call `CreatePayment` in your backend, with the `customer_id` and the `customer_card_id` as the source.

As for "connecting it to the Customers API" - you don't connect it directly per se. You would collect information from the customer, on your own, and pass it directly to the Customers API to create a customer. You can then call `CreateCustomerCard` using the nonce (generated by In-App Payments), and the `customer_id` that you just created, to save the card to this customer profile.

Comment: Incredibly helpful, thank you! I had assumed that plugin uses Google Pay.

Comment: Another question if you don't mind, just to confirm. Do you know if it's possible to charge the user's card even while not in the app? I.e, do they need to enter the CVV again or click a Buy Now button? Or can we charge them on the backend whenever we need to? It will be made abundantly clear to the user that their card will be used like this. Worldpay seems to have this requirement.

Comment: Also, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65985385/retrieve-card-details-and-charge-a-user-later-stripe for more clarity on what I want to do.

Comment: Yep, you can definitely call `CreatePayment` with the `customer_id` and `customer_card_id` at any point; they do not need to be within the app. With that said, you should get the customer's permission beforehand of course (about saving it on file).

Comment: @DaraJavaherian The above link is not working. :(

Comment: Woocommerce square plugin allow customer to save their card info and used them for next orders. So it is prebuilt. Do I need to set something on sqaure account ? @sjosey